# Smarty and AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, smarty

I am trying to implement the angularjs on a project that was used Smarty (PHP Template Engine).

The first problem I found was the problem in the template rendering, due to angularjs tag use braces ({) and the smarty variables.

I managed to solve this first problem by following this article: http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=87895&sid=937f958d431612d078f0f42324e09c59

Now the page is being rendered, but angularjs is not working.

If anyone has any tips and be able to help me, I'm grateful.

[image]

Sincerely, Renan Porto.

Comment: Part of the reason for using Angular is the fact it takes templates and renders them client side. I would suggest having a simple .html page and then loading the data in as needed, the answer @rkalita gave should work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change start and end interpolation symbol using interpolateProvider service.

you can change {{var}} to [[var]] or any symbols.

```
angular.module('app', [])
 .config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how was the working code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbyc2.png